Does this consent screen have a name?
Just found this one:

Despite the illusion of control, it is actually a cognitive nightmare where users must choose options filled with technological jargon and even time frames. It also includes options to download (???) and print (???).
Anyway, besides being a dark pattern, does this type of consent screen have a specific name?

Wow, interesting way to take things too far! I thought 'Data Access Level' was meant for the user to access data on that platform, like a premium subscription.

I don't think it has a particular name, it's a WordPress plugin Coockie Notice for cookies consent that can be customized based on the type of acceptance, the quantity of info provided and time period.

You can see it in operation on this website and this website
All the hidden information makes sense of the download and print options.
The advantage is the user can clearly see what he/she is agreeing to, but it is still a simple "accept all", "accept only the essentials", etc. plus a time period. Personally I find it quite functional, all the information easily accessible in three buttons with a simple text, which is still the same as Basic, Medium and Premium.

Silver: Rejects all access and gives you highest level of privacy.
Gold: Accepts some access and gives you a balanced experience.
Platinum: Accepts all access and gives you the highest level of personalisation.


Nice find! I disagree with " the user can clearly see what he/she is agreeing to", the pattern is clearly made to confuse users: the "premium" is actually to provide all your info, which I doubt anyone would ever consider as a premium option. The silver is meant to be the "poor" option yet is actually the more valuable for the user (provide nothing in exchange)

If you look at the screenshots of the plugin link, you will see in the configuration that the button names are editable.

Maybe "Hero Banner"... I have heard lots of terms depending on how each IT team sees it. Sometimes, the term is wrongly named, but it explains the intention of the component.

@Devin  I found a web using the same plugin in Spanish: metronia.es

That consent panel simulates the well known pattern of showcasing multiple products packages from basic to premium and least expensive to most expensive (see example below). In the case of this consent panel: The more (privacy sensitive) information you provide the better the experience. But it fails to show the requirements and features upfront. A bigger problem is that the supporting text makes it look like it means exactly the opposite: the better the package, the better the privacy, assuming everyone understands that platinum has the highest value and silver the least. I agree that this is a dark pattern and should be avoided. But I don't think you will find a name for it. Maybe call it a (in this case: fake) SLA* options panel. Where "service" is obviously the debatable part.
Now that we know it's a WordPress plugin: this shows that there is still a lot of ignorance about how to deal with privacy legislation and how users will or should experience it.
*Service Level Agreement

